# Google analytic dashboard using codeigniter for multiple website from single google account

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have certain amount of client, we want to provide admin interface for each client to see their website's analytic, all the clients website are registered on analytic from single google account. i try using JavaScript api but its ask for login in google account. so how can i archive this??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Hello Analytics Javascrip](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api)?  Not sure if it can be done without having the user go through authentication.  You probably need to utilize the API at the server level to accomplish this.

I invite you to check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com) *(disclosure - I work with them)*.  Our service was built specifically to make it easy to integrate Google Analytics dashboards into CMS/Webhosting services.  [This Page](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/passinggoogleprofileid.html) describes how you can have a chart display data from different GA profiles.